# Fetch to-many relationship object with condition

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-queryset

I have `Album` model and album has many `Track` on it, I want to get purchased tracks by user(from `Album` entity), I mean I want fetch just tracks which is bought by user, but when I sets query on `Album` entity, it returns all tracks belongs to album:

```
album_list = Album.objects.filter(
    Q(track__orderitem__order__user=user) &
    Q(track__orderitem__order__is_paid=True)
)
```

But this query_set returns all tracks of albums, regardless to purchasing by user or not.

Any idea?

Comment: How about `Album.objects.filter(track__orderitem__order__user=user, track__orderitem__order__is_paid=True)`?

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. , but not difference, because I'm handling it via Q

Comment: Does the `Order.objects.filter(user=user, is_paid=True).prefetch_related('orderitems__track').values('orderitems__track')` do the job?

Comment: @AlexMorozov, I want to fetch `Album` data, not `Order`

Comment: Er, " I want to get purchased tracks by user" sounds to me like you want tracks, not albums. Can you show your models and the example result you want to get from the queryset?

Comment: @AlexMorozov  `Track` has a foreign key to `Album` , and I want to get purchased tracks in Album structure, by this, the result is collection of albums which has tracks are purchased by user

Comment: You mean, if an album has, say, 5 tracks, and a user has purchased 4 of them, your query should return an `Album` instance with `tracks` attribute filled by those 4 tracks, right? And if an album doesn't have a single track purchased by user, such an album shouldn't be among the results?

Comment: @AlexMorozov, yeah , exactly +1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100297/discussion-between-alex-morozov-and-moe-far).